# why wordpress pagination just work on first page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have customized my theme and created a custom post type named 'movies' and everything is right but on homepage I want to show all of the movies but when I use pagination it is OK on first page and it creates the other pages link but when I click on other pages link it creates the link but it just shows white page, nothing is shown on that page, the address is OK, and I've tested the theme on my localhost and it worked.

Here is my pagination code

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
//$args['paged'] = $paged;
$args= array('post_type' => array('post','movies'),'paged'=>$paged);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


// loop for all posts ( main page )
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post-wrapper">
            <div class="post-inner-wrapper">
                <div class="post-title">
                        <span class="title">
                         <?php the_title() ?>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <div class="post-outer-text">
                                <span class="post-inner-text">
                                    <?php echo get_the_content(''); ?>
                                </span>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="post-image">
                <?php  the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post-details">
                    <span class="calendar">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="calendar_text">
                            <?php the_date(); ?>
                            </span>
                    </span>
                <span class="author">
                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php the_author(); ?>
                    </span>
                <span class="view">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo get_post_view(get_the_ID()); ?>
                    </span>
                <span class="like">
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>256
                    </span>
                <span class="more">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">ادامه مطلب</a>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php

    }?>
    <div class="pagination">


    <?php global $wp_query;
    echo ($wp_query->max_num_pages);
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    $page = get_query_var('paged');
    $page = (!empty($page) ? $page : 1);

//            query_posts( 'category_name=category&showposts=2&paged='.$page);
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );?>

    </div>
<?php
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```